# device driver documentation for linux

Tags: linux, operating-system, linux-device-driver

in the book 2017 " UNIX and Linux System Administration " i've read the article below :

Modern systems manage their device files automatically. However, a few rare corner
cases may still require you to create devices manually with the mknod command.
So here’s how to do it:

```
mknod filename type major minor
```

Here, filename is the device file to be created, type is c for a character device or b
for a block device, and major and minor are the major and minor device numbers.
If you are creating a device file that refers to a driver that’s already present in your
kernel, ***check the documentation for the driver to find the appropriate major and
minor device numbers.***

where can i find this doc and how to find Major & Minor for a device driver ???

Comment: When a driver supports multiple devices the minor numbers are usually assigned in order from 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `cat /proc/devices` shows the character and block major device numbers in use by drivers in the currently running Linux kernel, but provides no information about minor device numbers.

There is a list of pre-assigned (reserved) device numbers in the Linux kernel user's and administrator's guide: [Linux allocated devices (4.x+ version)](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/devices.html). (The same list also appears in "Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt" in the Linux kernel sources.) The list shows how minor device numbers are interpreted for each pre-assigned character and block major device number.

Some major device numbers are reserved for local or experimental use, or for dynamic assignment:

```
  60-63 char    LOCAL/EXPERIMENTAL USE

  60-63 block   LOCAL/EXPERIMENTAL USE
        Allocated for local/experimental use.  For devices not
        assigned official numbers, these ranges should be
        used in order to avoid conflicting with future assignments.
```

```
 120-127 char   LOCAL/EXPERIMENTAL USE

 120-127 block  LOCAL/EXPERIMENTAL USE
        Allocated for local/experimental use.  For devices not
        assigned official numbers, these ranges should be
        used in order to avoid conflicting with future assignments.
```

```
 234-254    char    RESERVED FOR DYNAMIC ASSIGNMENT
        Character devices that request a dynamic allocation of major number will
        take numbers starting from 254 and downward.

 240-254 block  LOCAL/EXPERIMENTAL USE
        Allocated for local/experimental use.  For devices not
        assigned official numbers, these ranges should be
        used in order to avoid conflicting with future assignments.
```

```
 384-511 char   RESERVED FOR DYNAMIC ASSIGNMENT
        Character devices that request a dynamic allocation of major
        number will take numbers starting from 511 and downward,
        once the 234-254 range is full.
```

Character device drivers that call `alloc_chrdev_region()` to register a range of character device numbers will be assigned an unused major device number from the dynamic range. The same is true for character device drivers that call `__register_chrdev()` with the first argument (`major`) set to 0.

Some external ("out-of-tree") Linux kernel modules have a module parameter to  allow their default major device number to be specified at module load time. That is useful for drivers that do not create their "/dev" entries dynamically, but want some flexibility for the system administrator to choose a major device number when creating device files manually with `mknod`.

Answer (score 1):

docs:
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596000081/ch03s02.html

https://tldp.org/LDP/tlk/dd/drivers.html

```
how to find the appropriate minor & major number for a device number:
ls -l /dev/
cat /proc/devices  shows the same as lsblk
```